# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '),

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `NavigateNija`.`FUTA`(
  `Id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `_RoadSideArea` CHAR(255)NOT NULL,
  `_Img` BLOB,
  `_Tamt` DOUBLE(10),
  `_MofT` CHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(`Id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation 
>    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 
>    `` '),    `_MofT` CHAR(50),    PRIMARY KEY(`Id`)  ) ENGINE = InnoDB' ``
>   at line 5

Comment: [`DOUBLE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/double/). Looks like you have to specify two numbers (M and D) or none. Maybe you intended `DOUBLE(10,0)` but it's not  clear and apparently the product doesn't guess.

Comment: It's rare to use DOUBLE. DECIMAL is more common (and, I suspect, more appropriate in this instance)

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the DOUBLE(10) and go with DOUBLE:

```
 CREATE TABLE `FUTA`(
  `Id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `_RoadSideArea` CHAR(255)NOT NULL,
  `_Img` BLOB,
  `_Tamt` DOUBLE,
  `_MofT` CHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(`Id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The DOUBLE datatype accepts either no parameters or two parameters (the number of digits allowed to be stored in the number and the number of digits allowed after the decimal point). [Reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/double/)

Comment: Or, ditch the `DOUBLE`, and go with `DECIMAL(m,n)`.  The IEEE floating point type has the advantage of storing a vast range of values, from mind numbingly *huge* values to the infinitesimally *tiny*. When we are storing values in an expected range (e.g. dollar amounts ranging from a penny to a trillion dollars, we typically use a DECIMAL datatype.

Comment: Yeah, typically the better option, unless we are doing work for NASA